# Rendering multiple paragraphs of text?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

For the past few days, I've been making a bunch of low quality games as a practice, most of them only involved little to no text, but this time, I wanted to make a real game, a simulation one that would rely heavily on dialogues, my way of rendering texts is this:

```
int message;
stringstream sstr;
sstr << message;
string message1 = sstr.str();

TTF_Font* Sans = NULL;
Sans = TTF_OpenFont("Sans.ttf", 24);
SDL_Color White = {255, 255, 255};  
SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = NULL;
surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, message1.c_str(), White);
SDL_Texture* Message = NULL;
Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage);

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Message, NULL, &Message_rect);
```

As you can see, I don't exactly use surfaces, the code above is just an example of how I try to call texts from variables, but what if I wanted to make paragraphs appear in a dialogue box? Personally, I could make them... in this way, like setting up rect after converting the surface into texture, and the likes but I've got a strong feeling that it's technically wrong and there might be a shorter and easier way to do it, so is there? and could you please maybe give me a sample? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried just adding newlines to the text?

Comment: Yep, that's actually the way I'm doing it right now, but making in-game dialogues would need a new sentence popping up every time they press an key or button, and as you can see, my method could only call a series of text in one time, and as I said, a game dialogue only pops out a few lines, which would mean that if I wanted to do the dialogues then the code would be really enormous....